# Do you need to restart Heroku after every migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

Recently I had an issue where my db scheme change wasn't being reflected on Heroku PG. I double checked to see that both migration and seed succeeded. What was even weirder was that the db scheme change worked fine on a staging heroku deployment (after the exact same migration/seed). After some searching around, I learned that you are supposed to restart heroku after migrations via:

```
heroku restart --app=app_name
```

I've never had to do this (I'm not exactly a veteran, but I've run a good amount of migrations before and have never had to restart heroku for this particular reason).

Do I actually need to be restarting heroku after each migration? Or is this more of a case by case thing?

Comment: Hey Tristan, I ran into exactly this issue. My migration worked fine on a staging app, but Rails didn't pick up the schema changes after the migration in production. I've never had to restart the dyno before and am curious why it was necessary in this case. Did you ever find out why restarting was necessary in production and not in staging?

Comment: Were you using `pipelines:promote` to promote from staging --> production?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you make changes to your DB via migrations then you will need to restart the application on Heroku. When Rails starts in production mode it caches the DB schema. Migrations run in one off processes which the running web process is not aware of. So for it to pick up the changes you need to restart at least your web processes. If your application was idling when you deployed and you ran the migrations it would pick up the new schema as the app started.

Comment: Updating my previous advice, you can run `rake db:schema:cache:clear` and it works. Verified with Rails 4.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get your app to pick up the new migration. Restarting the app works just fine. Or you can clear the schema cache:

```
heroku run rake db:schema:cache:clear --app=app_name
```

Comment: I admit I haven't tried this on Heroku yet (I'm not comfortable doing it in production without a decent chance that it will work right), but based on how I understand the schema cache works, it seems that running this rake task on Heroku will not actually clear the schema cache on the individual dynos. That is, the dynos store their own cache, and rake tasks on run on their own dynos.

Does this mean that this rake task is not actually compatible with Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

It depends i guess. Speaking generally, the answer is **NO**. If you restart your app locally after every migration, then it is needed else i don't think it is required .