# Ruby scaffolding link not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, scaffolding

So I believe that I have searched on here and not found any question that pertains to my issue so hopefully someone can guide me. I was required (for a course) to create a Ruby scaffolding "products" page. My page links all worked on the local host rails server but when I tried it on Heroku (also required) all the links work EXCEPT the new product page.

I have exhaustively googled but I must admit that all the computer lingo is new to me so I am unsure what any of it means and of what steps are safe. For the reason that if I make things worse, I will never know what to look for to reverse anything. I have included the error that shows up in Heroku. When I searched that I found many different answers causing me to be unsure which is correct.

If anything else is needed just let me know. Many thanks to any and all that reply!

[Error on Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21u2N.png)

Comment: Please include the error in the text of your answer instead of linking to it.

Comment: That’s a screen shot of the error. Does that not work

Comment: [Linking to screenshots is discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) when the question is unclear without the linked information, as in this case.

Comment: My apologies moveson, I thought my question was clear. Please let me know what I need to add so I can better understand what is required of an overstack  question. I really would like to get pointed in the right direction for all the frustration it’s causing me grrrrr

Comment: As I already mentioned, in order to make the question clear you should include the text to which your link refers.

Comment: Ok great! Going forward I will remember that thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error says, "relation products" does not exist.

Did you make sure to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` ? After you migrate you'll need to `heroku restart`

This gets me a lot as part of my Heroku deployments, so I make sure to write a script or rake task which does the git push to deploy to Heroku, then runs these two commands. Then I always use that script to deploy, instead of manually doing a push.

Comment: I will definitely try that. I know I did the migrate but don’t recall a restart as part on the steps

Comment: @Tabz https://stackoverflow.com/a/23838663/1937435 for why it's — at least sometimes — required.

Comment: Thank you thank you both! It's working!! I tried voting on the answer but it won't let me :/